# Выводить среднее значение столбца с MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server

Есть готовый код по графикам ,и теперь мне просто нужно по этому запросу

```
$query =  "SELECT  STATE,CODE,UPDATE_TIME FROM IO_DATA 
           WHERE (" . $query_txt .") AND 
           UPDATE_TIME >= '". $start_date . "' AND 
           UPDATE_TIME <= '". $end_date . "'";
```

Выводить среднее значение по столбику **STATE**  .

*Есть столбик **CODE** группировка идет по нему , в **CODE** есть значения 21,22,23,24,25,26 - это как бы обьекты ,например для 21 обьекта есть куча данных и их нужно усреднить ,так же и для 22 ,23,24,25,26 .*

По идее как я понял нужно просто добавить **AVG** типа

```
"SELECT AVG (STATE),CODE,UPDATE_TIME FROM IO_DATA 
 WHERE (" . $query_txt .") AND 
 UPDATE_TIME >= '". $start_date . "' AND 
 UPDATE_TIME <= '". $end_date . "'";
```

Так или где-то ошибка ?

Comment: В данном случаи, avg у вас не будет работать. Нужна группировка по полю (ORDER BY). Только вот из вашего запроса не понятно какие данные у вас есть и что надо группировать

Comment: GROUP BY так-то

Comment: Можно какой-то пример ?

Comment: Сейчас подкорректирую вопрос.

Comment: Все, описал более подробно

Comment: *По идее как я понял нужно просто добавить AVG типа* Вам нужно либо исключить все остальные поля из списка вывода (если нужно среднее по всему массиву - `SELECT AVG(STATE) FROM ...`), либо оставить те поля, для групп по которым нужно среднее, и добавить GROUP BY по этим полям (скажем, `SELECT AVG (STATE), CODE FROM ... GROUP BY CODE`).

Comment: Понял,спасибо )